# Custom Filepath Exporting a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, export, filepath

I am working with financial data, and I am cleaning the data in Python before exporting it as a CSV. I want this file to be reused, so I want to make sure that the exported files are not overwritten. I am including this piece of code to help with this:

```
# Fill this out; this will help identify the dataset after it is exported
latestFY = '21'
earliestFY = '19'
```

I want the user to change the earliest and latest fiscal year variables to reflect the data they are working with, so when the data is exported, it is called `financialData_FY19_FY21`, for example. How can I do this using the `to_csv` function?

Here is what I currently have:

```
mergedDF.to_csv("merged_financial_data_FY.csv", index = False)
```

Here is what I want the file path to look like: `financialData_FY19_FY21` where the 19 and 21 can be changed based on the input above.

Comment: Do you know how to concatenate strings? This is basic Python, nothing to do with pandas or `to_csv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an f-string to update the strings that will be your file paths.

```
latestFY = '21'
earliestFY = '19'
filename = f"merged_financial_data_FY{earliestFY}_{latestFY}.csv"
mergedDF.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

[Link to docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)